# How can i can freeze credit held by another account in Stellar SDK?

Tags: java-sdk

I read the guide from stellar.org but still couldn't find a solution. This is the guide:

https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/issuing-assets.html https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/assets.html#revoking-access

In their guide it says that as an anchor, I can freeze credit held by another account. I set the AUTHORIZATION REVOCABLE to true, but I still couldn't find how to freeze a specific account credit.

This was the code in the stellar guide

```
import org.stellar.sdk.AccountFlag;
Network.useTestNetwork();
Server server = new Server("https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org");
// Keys for issuing account
KeyPair issuingKeys = KeyPair
.fromSecretSeed("SCZANGBA5YHTNYVVV4C3U252E2B6P6F5T3U6MM63WBSBZATAQI3EBTQ4");
 AccountResponse sourceAccount = server.accounts().account(issuingKeys);

 Transaction setAuthorization = new Transaction.Builder(sourceAccount)
 .addOperation(new SetOptionsOperation.Builder()
  .setSetFlags(
   AccountFlag.AUTH_REQUIRED_FLAG.getValue() |
    AccountFlag.AUTH_REVOCABLE_FLAG.getValue())
   .build())
  .build();
 setAuthorization.sign(issuingKeys);
 server.submitTransaction(setAuthorization);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by revoking the authorization via the [Allow Trust](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/list-of-operations.html#allow-trust) 
operation. 
The Bifrost code contains an example how the authorization is set for `AUTH_REVOCABLE_FLAG` assets.

```
build.AllowTrust(
    build.SourceAccount{ac.IssuerPublicKey},
    build.Trustor{trustor},
    build.AllowTrustAsset{tokenAssetCode},
    build.Authorize{true},
)
```

See: https://github.com/stellar/go/blob/master/services/bifrost/stellar/transactions.go#L37

You can **revoke** it later with the same command by setting `build.Authorize{false}`